# Unable to delete a subnet I created in GCP

Tags: google-compute-engine, subnet

I have a subnet in GCP, under the **default** network, called **xxx-general**

If I try to delete this subnet (as it's no longer required), I get an error:

**Failed to delete the subnet. Error: The subnetwork resource 'projects/xxxxx-cloud-network/regions/europe-west2/subnetworks/xxx-general' is already being used by 'projects/xxxxx-cloud-network/regions/europe-west2/addresses/g000001'**

Instance **g000001** doesn't even exist.
I have looked around GCP, at the instances and VPC Network configs etc, but I can't see why this network thinks it's attached to anything.

I have tried creating g000001 and ensuring it's assigned to another subnet, but it doesn't help.

Does anyone know how to delete the subnet?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the VMs have been deleted the only way is to use command line to delete the Internal Reserved IP addresses.

Open Cloud Shell and connect it to the correct project then run the highlighted commands:

```
user123@cloudshell:~ (cellular-project-258333)$ gcloud compute addresses list
NAME          ADDRESS/RANGE  TYPE      PURPOSE       NETWORK  REGION       SUBNET      STATUS
k8s-worker-1  10.175.0.4     INTERNAL  GCE_ENDPOINT           us-central1  k8s-subnet  RESERVED
k8s-worker-2  10.175.0.5     INTERNAL  GCE_ENDPOINT           us-central1  k8s-subnet  RESERVED
k8s-worker-3  10.175.0.6     INTERNAL  GCE_ENDPOINT           us-central1  k8s-subnet  RESERVED


user123@cloudshell:~ (cellular-project-258333)$cloud compute addresses delete k8s-worker-1 k8s-worker-2 k8s-worker-3 --region us-central1                                                      
The following addresses will be deleted:
 - [k8s-worker-1] in [us-central1]
 - [k8s-worker-2] in [us-central1]
 - [k8s-worker-3] in [us-central1]

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  Y

Deleted [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/cellular-project-258333/regions/us-central1/addresses/k8s-worker-1].
Deleted [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/cellular-project-258333/regions/us-central1/addresses/k8s-worker-2].
Deleted [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/cellular-project-258333/regions/us-central1/addresses/k8s-worker-3].
```

Now the network resources such as subnets and VPCs can be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a static reserved internal IP named g000001. I do not believe it is an instance as suggested by ...../addresses/g000001.

Once you delete that IP address, you should get better results.

Comment: This is what I assumed but the guide at [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-internal-ip-address#deleting_a_static_internal_ip_address) doesn't work.

1) It assumes the instance exists and has a static IP.
2) Even if I create the instance (named exactly the same), it creates with an ephemeral (auto) IP.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it.

Despite the error only pertaining to Region europe-west2, the Zone in which I needed to recreate the instance (in order to re-apply and re-release the static internal IP) does matter.

I was recreating instance g000001 in europe-west2-a - which wasn't getting me anywhere.
When I recreated instance g000001 in europe-west2-c, I could change the ephemeral IP to static (at which point I could select the troublesome pre-defined static 10.16.1.x entry from a dropdown).

Once those settings were committed and the instance was created, I went back in and edited the g000001 instance, released the internal static IP, saved it, deleted the instance... and voila, I was then able to delete the subnet.

I can only imagine that when I deleted g000001 originally, GCP doesn't delete/release the reserved IPs in the background.